# What does the ~ do in C#?

Tags: c#

I just encountered this line in our code:

```
inspectActionResult.WorkActionResult &= ~WorkActionResult.Error;
```

WorkActionResult is a numbered enum, but what does the `~` do???

Comment: A [bitwise complement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d2bd4x66.aspx).

Comment: @bas Are you aware that C# is comprehensively documented? You might benefit from locating that documentation for future reference. It should be able to help you learn.

Comment: yeah yeah, I know :). I DID google first, should've came up with the idea of actually writing out "C# tilde"... since "C# ~ enum" didn't give me much. Sorry... :) (at least I get properly downvoted for it)

Comment: I would suggest you to use http://symbolhound.com/ to search for such programming terms. Google usually can't find relevant answers for symbols. Look at the [result for ~ C#](http://symbolhound.com/?q=~+C%23) from symbolhound

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is the logical (bitwise) NOT operator. It will flip all the bits of the operand, and return the result.

In your case, it is un-setting the bit represented by `WorkActionResult.Error` (due to the &= before it).

Comment: WOW! that's a fast answer! thx

Comment: With your reps I can't imagine that you don't know if a duplicate would exists or not.

Comment: @user2711965 Its a duplicate of the second question linked without a doubt (although without the context of unsetting a bit). Not so sure about the first one. Regardless, I was not aware of either of those questions, and would have marked as duplicate if I was.